# Transparent background in Windows Forms?

Tags: winforms, vb6, transparency, rgb

I would like to transparent red color form background of *visual basic 6* program.

I use this code to make the background of the form transparent:

```
Option Explicit

Private Const GWL_EXSTYLE As Long = (-20)
Private Const LWA_COLORKEY As Long = &H1
Private Const LWA_Defaut As Long = &H2
Private Const WS_EX_LAYERED As Long = &H80000

Private Declare Function GetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias _
    "GetWindowLongA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function SetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias _
    "SetWindowLongA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long, _
    ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function SetLayeredWindowAttributes Lib "user32" _
    (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal crKey As Long, ByVal bDefaut As Byte, _
    ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long

Private Sub Form_Load()
  Me.BackColor = RGB(254,0,0)
  Transparency Me.hWnd, Me.BackColor, 255
End Sub

Private Sub Transparency(ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lngTransparentColor As Long, _
ByVal bytTransparency As Byte)

    Dim lngwindowstyle As Long

    lngwindowstyle = GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE)
    If (lngwindowstyle And WS_EX_LAYERED) <> WS_EX_LAYERED Then
        SetWindowLong hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, lngwindowstyle Or WS_EX_LAYERED
    End If

    SetLayeredWindowAttributes hWnd, lngTransparentColor, bytTransparency, _
    LWA_COLORKEY Or LWA_Defaut
End Sub
```

But as you can see in the picture the **red** noise remains :

[image: transparent background vb6]

How can I remove this noise?

---

I saved the picture with `.png` extension and use `AlphaImageControl.ocx` to show it.

The red noise is removed but a red line under form remains :

[image: transparent background png]

Comment: Your code is fine. Do you have a picture assigned to your Form's `Picture` property or some other `Image` or `PictureBox` on your form that's causing the "extra" red?

Comment: I have a picture at Form's `Picture` property, no `Image` no `PictureBox`

Comment: Does the picture have that redness in it?

Comment: The transparent color works with exact matches of RGB values. You have some pixels in your picture that are not exactly RGB 254, 0, 0 but another shade of red. Any pixels that are to be transparent must be **exactly** that color. Edit the picture in an image-editor.

Comment: Your can't use this effect for antialiasing. If your picture has any other red value other than RGB(254,0,0) it's going to appear.

Comment: ok,when save picture with .jpg This problem occurred,i use .png ,but have new problem,edit post

Comment: I expect it is still the same problem. I expect those pixels are not exactly  RGB 254, 0, 0

Comment: i  transparent red background of picture and save `.png` and use `AlphaImageControl.ocx` to show in form and set background color of form **RGB 254, 0, 0** so all red color is 254, 0, 0

Comment: plus 1 for question

Answer (score 2):

As the commenters already said, your "red" isn't always the same red. The line under the form remains, if you look closely you can see it: the red lines are fading from red to black. So even if your left pixel is 254,0,0 the next ones are not. I recommend using a blank/real transparent background, png offers you that :)

Comment: As an aside, this issue of color consistency is why many magic-eraser or auto-select tools come with a "cutoff" variable in common image editing applications.